# Having trouble with node name sizes for semPaths

Tags: r, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model, semplot

So far, this is the code I have for my structural equation model:

```
#### Libraries ####
library(lavaan)
library(semPlot)

#### Cov Matrix ####

# Load
lower <- "
2.60
0.74  1.20
0.66  0.52  4.50
0.64  0.57  2.46  4.54
0.64  0.61  1.22  1.33  2.28
0.84  0.68  1.01  0.91  1.68  2.44
0.63  0.59  0.81  0.89  1.42  1.82  3.11
"

# Save
cov <- getCov(lower, lower=T)

#### Model ####

model <- "

# Latent variables:
Happy =~ V5 + V6 + V7
Prosoc =~ V1 + V2
Recog =~ V3 + V4

# Regressions:
Happy ~ a*Recog
Happy ~ b*Prosoc
Recog ~ c*Prosoc

# Indirects:
Direct := a
Indirect := a*c
Total := Direct + Indirect
"

#### Fit ####
fit  <- sem(model, sample.cov = cov, sample.nobs = 243)

#### Summary ####
summary(fit, fit.measures = T, standardized =T)

#### Plot ####

# Labels:
label <- c("H1","H2","H3","P1","P2","R1","R2","Happy","Prosoc","Recog")
semPaths(fit,
         color = "lightblue",
         theme="colorblind",
         whatLabels = "std",
         style = "lisrel",
         sizeLat = 10,
         sizeLat2 = 10,
         sizeMan = 7,
         edge.color = "steelblue",
         edge.label.cex = 1.5,
         rotation = 2,
         layout = "tree2",
         intercepts = T,
         residuals = T,
         curve = 2,
         title = T,
         title.color = "black",
         cardinal = "lat cov",
         residScale = 15,
         curvePivot = T,
         nodeLabels = label,
         mar = c(2,5,2,5.5))

#### Title ####
title("DF = 11, Chi = 22.641, P < 0.02
 CFI: .979, TLI: .959, RMSEA: .066, SRMR: .035")
```

Which gives me this passable, but not perfect path diagram. You can see here that despite resizing the latents and manifests, you can barely read them if at all:

[image]

My question is: how can I resize the text so it can better fit in each node? Is that even possible? My problem is that the R help page isn't always clear what can and can't be included in semPaths, as it seems at least loosely based off qgraphs from what I gather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

label.cex controls size of text in nodes. You try

```
label.cex = 1.5
```

or resize to see what fits